# How to insert a new key with a value in a specific position into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddict

I have a huge List of dictionary like this which has almost 100 entries.

```
[{ "color":-65536, 
  "touch_size":0.21960786,
  "touch_x":831.25,
  "touch_y":1597.2656
},
{ "color":-65536,
  "touch_size":0.20392159,
  "touch_x":1302.5,
  "touch_y":1496.0938
}, .... {}]
```

I want to insert 2 new keys with values in each dictionary on a particular position.

```
new_keys = ['touch_x_dp','touch_y_dp']
```

`touch_x_dp` needs to be placed after key `touch_x` and `touch_y_dp` needs to be placed after `touch_y`
The values for these need to be initialized with None.

I have tried this but this does not place them where I need.

```
for key in dp_keys:data['attempts'][i]["items"][j][key]=None
```

Comment: can you explain why you need this in a particular order

Comment: Dictionaries were unordered pre- Python 3.7 and are sorted by order of insertion in newer versions, so you might have to use `OrderedDict` depending on your version and will need to reconstruct the dictionaries in either case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert key-value pair into dictionary at a specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390818/insert-key-value-pair-into-dictionary-at-a-specified-position)

Comment: @Rahul I need to printout the values of these keys into a excel using the xlsx writer.

Comment: For you apparent use-case, [named tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970608/4996248) might be preferable to dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Python is 3.7+, you can do the following:

```
data = [{"color": -65536,
         "touch_size": 0.21960786,
         "touch_x": 831.25,
         "touch_y": 1597.2656
         },
        {"color": -65536,
         "touch_size": 0.20392159,
         "touch_x": 1302.5,
         "touch_y": 1496.0938
         }]

fields_order = ["color", "touch_size", "touch_x", "touch_x_dp", "touch_y", "touch_y_dp"]
payload = []
for d in data:
    entity = dict([(f, d.get(f)) for f in fields_order])
    payload.append(entity)

print(payload)
# output: [{'color': -65536, 'touch_size': 0.21960786, 'touch_x': 831.25, 'touch_x_dp': None, 'touch_y': 1597.2656, 'touch_y_dp': None}, {'color': -65536, 'touch_size': 0.20392159, 'touch_x': 1302.5, 'touch_x_dp': None, 'touch_y': 1496.0938, 'touch_y_dp': None}]
```

For Python<3.7, you should use `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

fields_order = ["color", "touch_size", "touch_x", "touch_x_dp", "touch_y", "touch_y_dp"]
payload = []
for d in data:
    entity = OrderedDict([(f, d.get(f)) for f in fields_order])
    payload.append(entity)

print(payload)
```

Answer (score -4):

There is no buildin method to put some key in some order in python dicts.
You can write your own function that resigns every key after inserting but 
in general, it is not a good idea to rely on keys orders.