# How to update a dictionary at specific positions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dictionary like below:

```
data = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

Is there any way to update my above dictionary after particular key? For example you want to add `'b':4` after `'a':1`, and at the end add `'E':6` — so final output map should look like below:

```
data = {'a': 1, 'b':4, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'E':6}
```

I have gone through some documentation but I did not find any reference where we can update dictionary at particular position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert key-value pair into dictionary at a specified position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390818/insert-key-value-pair-into-dictionary-at-a-specified-position)

Comment: @EricMarchand since 3.7, `dict` insertion order is guaranteed.

Comment: Dictionaries aren't semantically ordered data structures (_even though_ they now retain insertion order - equality comparisons ignore order, for example) so this operation doesn't really make sense. Even the explicitly [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) doesn't have an "insert at" method. Could you provide some context as to why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you updated your `data` dict with like this below:

```
data = {'a': 1,  'd': 3,  'c': 2, 'e':6, 'b':4}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
# x[0] is referring to the key here. if you want to sort based on the value
# then it will be x[1]

sort_orders = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

which will give:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 6}
```

Note: this might be case sensitive while sorting the order.

Comment: It will _definitely_ be case sensitive. And don't use code formatting for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

May this solve your problem and the return value is also dict not list

```
import operator
data = {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
data['b'] = 4
data['e'] = 6

sorted_d = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

Output

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 6}
```

Comment: This is more specific to sorted pattern, what if i have dict which key contain mix of word? like ```IsPrimaryKey: false, IsRequired: false, Name: 'test'```

Comment: You mean, you want to add a new element at specific index