# how to add new item into dictionary in specific index of that dict

Tags: python

```
my_dict={1:'monday',2:'tuesday',4:'thursday',5:'friday',6:'saturday'}
```

Now I need to add an item like `(3:'wednesday')`  between the second item and 3rd item in the given dictionary. Is that possible ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390818/how-to-insert-key-value-pair-into-dictionary-at-a-specified-position

Comment: Yes, its possible, but why would you? Once done you can always access the string: `'wednesday'` through the key `3` wherever it ends up (once printed, say)

Comment: i want to know how we can add an item in specific index  , because we can't use append or extend unless there is a list in a dictionary, we can use update but it gets added in the last .

Comment: I don't think you do want to know these things. Why do you want these things?

Comment: you can help , if you know .

Comment: Yes, I want to help you. I want to help you to realise that you don't need what you are asking for. What future operations do you want to perform on `my_dict`?

Comment: Please fix the typo: `1:'monday.2:'`

Comment: @AksharSahul - for `dict` you don't need `index` as `list` `(there is none)`.  It goes by finding the `key` (3, in your case), and it's faster O(1).  So your question is unclear to us.

Comment: am just practicing, am new to python and i explored in other pages, no one is saying this. so am expecting some help here.

Comment: You are getting help here: Just update `my_dict` with your additional data and move on. Your `dict` will perform how you want it to perform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert key-value pair into dictionary at a specified position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390818/how-to-insert-key-value-pair-into-dictionary-at-a-specified-position)

Answer (score 2):

The question does not really make sense, since there is no 2nd or 3rd item (whatever you mean by item) in Python dictionary, and neither there is a concept of "between".  `dict` is guaranteed to remember order of keys inserted (since Python 3.7), but that order is not considered "important": e.g., it's not impacting comparisons:

```py
>>> dict_1 = {1: 'monday', 2: 'tuesday'}
>>> dict_2 = {2: 'tuesday', 1: 'monday'}
>>> dict_1 == dict_2
True
>> dict_1 is dict_2
False
```

You can manipulate that order by re-adding key/value pairs, but if your data structure considers ordering important, use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).  It doesn't have a method for inserting at arbitrary "position", but you can use its `move_to_end()` method to change the order afterwards.